# WPF Header of the row-header column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridrowheader

I need to add an Header on my Row-Header Column.

My `DataGrid` is a custom `DataGrid`.

This is my `Row-Header`:

```
<Datagrids:ImpDataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Linea}" />
    </Style>
</Datagrids:ImpDataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

What should I do to add an Header to my `RowHeader` Column?

Comment: Wouldn't it just become a simple column with a different style?

Comment: Anyway, by default, the DataGrid doesn't support this... You'd have to edit the DataGrid's Template and add a new control in the upper-left corner where you can put whatever you want.